# .find() method: How i can return a boolean instead my finded object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a multiple select and i'm using a `.find()` with the checked property to select the `checkbox` when the value is in the two arrays.

This is my list array:

```
const permissionsGroupList = [
    { name: 'Seller' },
    { name: 'Admins' }
];

   const [groupPermissions, setGroupPermissions] = useState([]);

<Select
  labelId="mult-check-permissions"
  id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
  multiple
  label="Grupo de permissões"
  onChange={handleChangeGroupPermissions}
  value={groupPermissions}
  input={<Input disableUnderline={true} />}
  renderValue={selected => selected.join(", ")}
>
  {permissionsGroupList.map(permissionGroup => (
    <MenuItem key={permissionGroup.name} value={{ name: permissionGroup.name }}>
      <Checkbox
        checked={groupPermissions.find(
          group => group.name === permissionGroup.name
        )}
      />
      <ListItemText primary={permissionGroup.name} />
    </MenuItem>
  ))}
</Select>;
```

In my method `.find()` is returning the object that is found, how I can return `true/false` instead? I'm receiving this error because the `Checkbox` component expect a boolean

> index.js:1 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `checked` of type
>   `object` supplied to `ForwardRef(Checkbox)`, expected `boolean`.

Comment: You can replace `.find(` by [`.some(`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: What about `.includes`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @evolutionxbox that also works with `groupPermissions.includes(permissionGroup.name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate if it returned a value with `!!`.

For example using as the following:

```
<Checkbox checked={!!groupPermissions.find(
                     group => group.name === permissionGroup.name
                  )}
/>
```

Think about the following:

```js
const data = [1,2,3];

const result1 = !!data.find(e => e === 17);
const result2 = !!data.find(e => e === 2);

console.log(result1); // not found
console.log(result2); // found
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which is made for returning a boolean.

```
checked={groupPermissions.some(
    group => group.name === permissionGroup.name
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this below:

```
    <Checkbox
            checked={groupPermissions.some( group => group.name === permissionGroup.name
 ))}
    />
```

Check this link here:

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method for this like:

```
<Checkbox checked={groupPermissions.some({name}=> name === permissionGroup.name)}/>
```

- The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value. So, this will be useful in this scenario.

You can also use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and `length` property for this like:

```
<Checkbox checked={!!groupPermissions.filter({name}=> name === permissionGroup.name).length}/>
```

- The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. So, if it finds `permissionGroup.name` in the `groupPermissions` array then `length` will be a value > 0 and `!!` will convert that to `true`, else you will get `false`.